# update multiple rows in one sql query

Tags: php, mysql

Im new in php. this problem stuck me for two days. ergh. I want to display a table that contain input field so that user can insert the data and update it into database. User can change all the data in the table. I want to update multiple rows at a time, but it ends up updating only 1 row (the last row). Anyone please help me for this. Thnks.
[This are the form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbVFa.jpg)
This are the following code.

```
    [<table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
         <td><b>Item Code</b></td>
         <td><b>Item Barcode</b></td>
         <td><b>Item</b></td>
         <td><b>QOH</b></td>
         <td><b>Quantity</br>Checked</b></td>
         <td><b>Quantity</br>Order</b></td>                            
         </tr>
      </thead>
<?php
$Barcode=$_SESSION\["Barcode"\];
$code=$_SESSION\["Code"\];
$itemcode=$_SESSION\["Itemcode"\];
$guid=$_SESSION\["guid"\];

$sql = "SELECT itemmastersupcode.*, itembarcode.*, stock_count_item.*, stock_count.*, po_ex_c.*, d.itemlink_total_qty  
FROM itemmastersupcode 
WHERE stock_count.SupCode = '$code' and stock_count_item.TRANS_GUID = '$guid'
GROUP BY itemmastersupcode.Itemcode";
$result=mysqli_query($conn2,$sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  ?>

  <tbody>
     <tr>

     <td><?php echo $row\["Itemcode"\]; ?></td>

     <td><?php echo $row\["Barcode"\]; ?></td>

     <td><?php echo $row\["Description"\]; ?></td>

     <td><?php echo $row\["itemlink_total_qty"\]; ?></td>

     <td><?php echo $row\["qty"\]; ?></td>

     <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST" id="myForm">
     <td><input type="number" name="qty" value=""/></td>

     </tr>
     </tbody>

  <input type="hidden" name="itemcode" value="<?php echo $row\["itemcode"\]; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="supcode" value="<?php echo $_SESSION\["Code"\] ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="guid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION\["guid"\] ?>"/>

<?php   
  }
    ?>
    </table>

    <button name="save" type="submit" ><b>SUBMIT</b></button>
    </form>

    <?php
      if (isset($_POST\["save"\]))
       {

       $itemcode=$_POST\['itemcode'\];
       $qty=$_POST\['qty'\];
       $supcode=$_POST\['supcode'\];
       $guid=$_POST\['guid'\];


$sql = "UPDATE stock_count, stock_count_item SET stock_count.posted = '1', stock_count_item.qty_order = '$qty'
WHERE stock_count.TRANS_GUID = '$guid' AND stock_count_item.Itemcode ='$itemcode' 
and stock_count_item.TRANS_GUID = '$guid' ";][1]
```

Comment: for that you have to put update query in foreach loop .. for update mulltiple rows.

Comment: What's wrong with your formatting? All those slashes before the square brackets do not belong there.

Comment: you specify what column to be updated by `WHERE`. So if `where` contains multiple columns, it'll update multiple columns. Now the statement after `where` surely satisfy condition of 1 row not more. try changing them.

Comment: There's lots wrong here :-(. I suggest you break the problem down into manageable parcels- starting with the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

An `UPDATE` query will update all records that are filtered by the `WHERE` clause. If no `WHERE` is given, all records are updated:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1='value1';
```

will set the `field1` column of all records to `value1`.

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1='value1' WHERE field2='value2';
```

will set the `field1` column to `value1` or all records where `field2` is equal to `value2`.

So, in your case, the records that are found through the `WHERE` clause are updated. This is all basic SQL stuff by the way, so I advise you to read up on SQL.

Finally, also use prepared statements in your code to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score -2):

```
<table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
         <td><b>Item Code</b></td>
         <td><b>Item Barcode</b></td>
         <td><b>Item</b></td>
         <td><b>QOH</b></td>
         <td><b>Quantity</br>Checked</b></td>
         <td><b>Quantity</br>Order</b></td>                            
         </tr>
      </thead>
<?php
$Barcode=$_SESSION["Barcode"];
$code=$_SESSION["Code"];
$itemcode=$_SESSION["Itemcode"];
$guid=$_SESSION["guid"];

$sql = "SELECT itemmastersupcode.*, itembarcode.*, stock_count_item.*, stock_count.*, po_ex_c.*, d.itemlink_total_qty  
FROM itemmastersupcode 
WHERE stock_count.SupCode = '$code' and stock_count_item.TRANS_GUID = '$guid'
GROUP BY itemmastersupcode.Itemcode";
$result=mysqli_query($conn2,$sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  ?>

  <tbody>
     <tr>

     <td><?php echo $row["Itemcode"]; ?></td>

     <td><?php echo $row["Barcode"]; ?></td>

     <td><?php echo $row["Description"]; ?></td>

     <td><?php echo $row["itemlink_total_qty"]; ?></td>

     <td><?php echo $row["qty"]; ?></td>

     <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST" id="myForm">
     <td><input type="number" name="itemcode[<?php echo $row["itemcode"]; ?>][qty]" value=""/></td> //update here

     </tr>
     </tbody>

<?php   
  }
    ?>
    </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="supcode" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Code"] ?>"/> //update here
  <input type="hidden" name="guid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["guid"] ?>"/>//update here
    <button name="save" type="submit" ><b>SUBMIT</b></button>
    </form>
```

Php content

```
   <?php
      if (isset($_POST["save"]))
       {

       $itemcodes=$_POST['itemcode'];
       $qty=$_POST['qty'];
       $supcode=$_POST['supcode'];
       $guid=$_POST['guid']; 

$sql = "UPDATE stock_count, stock_count_item SET
 stock_count.posted = '1', 
 stock_count_item.qty_order = CASE  stock_count_item.Itemcode";
 foreach( $itemcodes as $itmcode=>$qty)
 {
        $sql.=" WHEN ".$itmcode." THEN ".$qty
 }
$sql.=" END  WHERE stock_count.TRANS_GUID =$guid AND stock_count_item.TRANS_GUID=$guid AND stock_count_item.Itemcode IN (".implode(",",array_keys(   $itemcodes)).") ";


?>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: why downvote i dont know, here i am using cases for updating record, and i hope 100% it will work

Comment: thanks for your response @Naisa purushotham. i will check the code